# State whether the equation for the two function is true

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Question:

For every pair of continuous function $f,g:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that

$$\max\{f(x):x \in [0,1]\} = \max\{g(x):x \in [0,1]\}$$

Is the statement $$(f(c))^2 + f(c) = (g(c))^2 + 3 g(c)$$ for some $c\in[0,1]$ true?

Answer is No.

The solution only showed when $f(c)=g(c)$, the statement is false. Hence No.

My question is how the above assumption is enough to falsify the statement. Why not at any other point the statement cannot be true?

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: You recieved an answer to your question. Is it what you needed? If so, consider accepting the answer. That's how the site works. If it is not what you needed, please explain what is still left unclear.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is not true in general. For example, if $f(x)=1$ for all $x$, and $g(x)=1$ for all $x$, then the equality $$\max\{f(x):x \in [0,1]\} = \max\{g(x):x \in [0,1]\}$$ is true, but $$(f(c))^2 + f(c) = (g(c))^2 + 3 g(c)$$ is not true.

---

Logically, if the statement says $\forall a: P(x)\implies Q(x)$, then in order to **disprove** the statement, we must prove its negation, which is
$$\exists a: P(x)\land \neg Q(x).$$

This also makes sense intuitively. If I claim "all things with property $P$ have property $Q$", then all you need to do to prove me wrong is to find **one** thing with property $P$ that does not have property $Q$.

Your statement is one such statement, saying that all pairs of functions that satisfy one equality also satisfy another equality. To disprove this, all you need to do is find one counterexample.

Your case